# segmentation fault ('core' generado)

Tags: c, ordenamiento

No entiendo porque sale el error de segmentation en mi ordenamiento por inserción.

```
int main(){
    int numeros[]={53,-231,32,12,76,-32,315,-2,-9,2,5,0,22};
    int size=sizeof(numeros)/sizeof(int);
    //seleccion(numeros,size);
    insercion(numeros,size);
    
}

void seleccion(int *numeros,int size){
    int menor,aux;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        menor=i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < size; j++){
            if( numeros[menor] > numeros[j] ){
                menor=j;
            }
        }
        aux=numeros[i];
        numeros[i]=numeros[menor];
        numeros[menor]=aux;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        printf("%i ",numeros[j]);
    }
}
void insercion(int *numeros,int size){
    int j,aux;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        j=i;
        while( (i != 0) && (numeros[j] < numeros[j-1])){
            intercambio(&numeros[j],&numeros[j-1]);
            j--;
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        printf("%i ",numeros[j]);
    }
}
void intercambio(int *menor,int *mayor){
    int aux=*menor;
    *menor=*mayor;
    *mayor=aux;
}
```

El problema lo solucione cambiando la variable 'i' del while por la 'j', pero no comprendo porque el error.

Comment: El error era porque cuando j = 0, Al hacer: numeros[j-1] el índice estaba fuera de rango, estabas haciendo una lectura a memoria invalida

Comment: Ahh ya, j se igualaba a -1, ahora entiendo, muchas gracias por responder algo tan obvio. :"v

Answer (score 0):

El error es muy sencillo: la variable de control `j`, inicialmente toma el valor `i`. Si los elementos `j` y `j-1` están desordenados, se intercambian, y se decrementa la variable de control con la instrucción `j--`.

La condición `i != 0` siempre se va a cumplir, porque el valor mínimo de `i` es 1, y solo va a ir creciendo, por lo que no hace nada. Sin embargo, cuando `i = 1`, se pondrá `j = 1`, y se comprobará si están desordenados.

Si están desordenados, se intercambiarán, y `j se decrementa`.

Como `i` sigue valiendo `1`, el bucle continúa, con `j = 0`, al realizar `numeros[j] < numeros[j-1]` estás intentando acceder a dos elementos del vector: `numeros[0]` y `numeros[-1]`.

Como puedes observar, el segundo índice, que es negativo, es el que provoca la violación de segmento.

Al forzar a que la segunda condición solo se ejecute cuando `j != 0` te estás asegurando de que no se acceda a ningún indice negativo.